# Marionette View is not render the second time the show method is called

Tags: backbone.js, marionette

There is a Marionette ItemView which is rendered correctly the first time as a bar at the left side of the window. The side bar can be hide and it happens correctly by calling the close method of the view. However, when I want to show the side bar again I create a new instance of the view and show it in the region it is not displayed. The initialize method is called as well as the onShow but the elements are not added to the DOM thus they are not shown in the screen. Thanks for your help in advance

Comment: I suggest you post some code. It's kinda hard to guess what might be the problem.

Comment: Are you setting 'el' in your view to hook up to an existing DOM element? If you then call 'remove()' on the view, that DOM element is gone. If not, post some code :)